# Android: duplicate values are being inserted in to database

Tags: android, sqlite

Each time i run the project same values are also being inserted in the android database. Even i have given the drop if exists  query.What i need is that the data in the database gets updated only if there are some changes in the response from the server side instead of cresting database every time but what is happening with me is that same values got insertes again in the tables. How do I solve this?   Following is my code:

```
     public  void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        try{
        //  onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion)
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("in on create db"+e);
    }}

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" +DATABASE_CREATE);
        onCreate(database);
    }


 private static final String INSERT = "insert into " 
         + DATABASE_TABLE + "(KEY_TYPE,KEY_ENCODING,KEY_WIDTH,KEY_HEIGHT,KEY_DATA,KeyIId)"+" values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       public WineDatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
         try{
           this.context = context;
           openHelper = new WineDatabaseHelper(context);
           this.db=openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
          this.insertStmt=this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
       }
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Need more visibility into your code to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

DROP TABLE seems a pretty extreme way of trying to stop duplicate values. It's a bit hard to follow the code you've posted, but the normal way of stopping duplicates is to add a unique index on the appropriate column(s). Have you tried that yet ? E.g. something like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_keytype ON tableName (key_type)
```

Comment: What i need is that the data in the database gets updated only if there are some changes in the response from the server side instead of cresting database every time but what is happening with me  is that same values got insertes again in the tables. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What does your schema look like? If you don't want duplicate rows and you know a certain column will be unique use the "UNIQUE" specifier on it. If what you really want is for the row to be replaced you have to use the databaseHelper command "replace" ie. dbHelper.replace(...);